# How to measure memory consumed by current process - service?

Tags: winapi

I need to determine memory usage for own running process that is Windows Service.

What I am looking is something similar [GetProcessMemoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219(v=vs.85).aspx) function from Windows API, but for Windows services. The help for all PSAPI functions says - desktop apps only.

Comment: No, its fine to call from a service, "desktop apps only" means its not available to store/phone apps.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. Bad wording from Microsoft.

Comment: @MarisB., "memory consumed" is ambiguous definition, be careful and determine what exactly you are looking for (e.g. see Windows Task Manager -> View -> Select Columns -> Memory *).

Comment: @KonstantinL, thanks for the pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That text in MSDN API documentation draws the distinction between classic Win32 programs (desktop apps) and modern store apps (store apps). As such your service qualifies as a desktop app, according to the terminology. Feel free to call `GetProcessMemoryInfo`.